# how to show data into view file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to show query result in the view against pressing the button.

Controller code

```
public function reservation(){

    $data['result']=$this->Books_model->get_reservations();
    $this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data);

}
```

Model code

```
  public function get_reservations(){

    $sql ="SELECT `reservation.reservation_id`, `reservation.rest_names`, `reservation.rest_start_time`, `reservation.rest_end_time`, `reservation.no_of_people`, `reservation.date_id` , `date.date_id`
    FROM `reservation`,`date`
    WHERE `reservation.date_id`=`date.date_id`";
    $query =$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();


}
```

and view file

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 pager">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number of People " id="number_of_people" name="no_people"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>

                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 pager">
                <label for="start_time" class="col-lg-2 pager">Start_Time</label>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <select  class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <option> Start Time </option>
                        <option> 1:00 </option>
                        <option> 2:00 </option>
                        <option> 3:30 </option>
                        <option> 4:00 </option>
                        <option> 5:00 </option>
                        <option> 6:00 </option>
                        <option> 7:00 </option>
  </select>

                </div>

            </div>


                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 pager"> <a href="" class="btn btn-warning"> check Availability  </a> </div>
    </div>
```

please guide me what i made change in my view file that i will get my desire output.

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983038/how-to-display-content-from-database-in-codeigniter-without-calling-controller-f

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The $data array you are passing to the view gives you variables equal to your keys (see the PHP extract() function). So in your case, you would be able to use $result in your view. Try this in your view to see it.

```
<?php
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$data['result'] = Anythings
$this->load->view('restaurants/booking',$data);
```

View restaurants/booking

```
<?=var_dump($result)?>
```

Best way to write model in codegintaor:

```
protected function get_reservations()
{

        $sql = "SELECT 
       `reservation.reservation_id`, 
       `reservation.rest_names`, 
       `reservation.rest_start_time`, 
       `reservation.rest_end_time`, 
       `reservation.no_of_people`, 
       `reservation.date_id` , 
       `date.date_id`
            FROM `reservation`,`date`
            WHERE `reservation.date_id`=`date.date_id`";

       $query =$this->db->query($sql);

       if($query->num_rows() > 0 )
       {
            return $query->row_array();// for one row
            or 
            return $query->result_array(); // for more then one row
       }

    }
```